# Coffeescript: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: coffeescript

I have a normal coffeScript loop for placing markers on google maps. However, i am getting the error. Here is the code. P.S: 2 weeks into coffeeScript

```
layMarkers = ->
    $.ajax '/locations',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'json'
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.log errorThrown
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            buses = data["locations"]
            for i in buses
              do (i) ->
                marker = new google.maps.Marker(position: new google.maps.LatLng(i["latitude"], i["longitude"]),
                map: map
                title: "#{i["number_plate"]}, #{i["speed"]}km/h"
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP)
                marker.setMap(map)
                marker.addListener 'click', ->
                  showDirection(i["terminal_number"], i["bus_number"], i["number_plate"],i["speed"] )
                  # infowindow("#{i["number_plate"]}, #{i["speed"]}km/h, Terminal: #{i["terminal_number"]}, Bus Number: #{i["bus_number"]}").open map, marker
                  return
```

Assist if you can. thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the output JavaScript? Your formatting is questionable at best...Why are you calling `.setMap` when you specify the map in the constructor call?

Comment: Also, be sure to post all relevant code, I'd guess the problem is that your `showDirection` function is recursing endlessly, but you don't show the code for it.